# Remove all fields except one from mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to remove all fields except "fName" from a document found by a field and if the document does not exist then create it.
Is there a way to do that at one go? thx

```js
myCol.update({fName: someName}, {fName: someName}); // works if doc exists, fails if no doc.

myCol.upsert({fName: someName}, {fName: someName}); // failed if doc exists, works if it exists
```

Comment: why don't you try fName :{$exists:true} in query part?

Comment: thx. I got it with `myCol.upsert({fName:{$exists:true}}, {fName: someName});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fName :{$exists:true}` in your query part.

This will update document only if `fName` in present.